# Getting the chat ID from call ID with the Skype API

Tags: c#, .net, skype

I'm writing a simple conference host in C# for the Skype API. When the program is notified that a call has ended, I want it to send the "/golive" command to the group chat associated with the call that just ended. I can do everything except retrieve the chat ID from the call, or even vice versa.

It appears from the API documentation, that there is no link between the chat and the call, but this makes no sense as you can only have one call per chat, and Skype gives you a "join call" button at the top of the chat, so Skype MUST link between the Chat and the call. Any ideas how to get at that information?

Answer (score 0):

go to the group chat profile, copy conversation link -> it will look like skype?chat&blob= 
delete that part then the api command is CHAT CREATEUSINGBLOB 
after that you get a #thisisyourchatid and you just chat to that address (including the #)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer you can use "/get uri" or "/get blob" chat command in a group chat to get blob.